# More optional \xx_use:N and \xx_new:N functions than documented?

Tags: expl3, latex3

From the documentation I know that `\tl_use:N` and `\str_use:N` are optional. Those variables can be used directly. **Isn’t that true for even more types?**

Is it likely that more `\xx_new:N` will be officially raised to that optional level as well (i.e. if overwriting is not an issue, intention of use need not be declared and **`\xx_set:Nn` can be called directly)?** (like with `\cs_set:Nn`)

Especially in the light of local variables.—I’m not going to start a habit of using `\l_tmpa_tl` instead of descriptive variable names (which I consider error-prone), so I’ll have a bunch of `\tl_new:N` hanging out of functions.

Comment: L3 can't change the fundamentals of the underlying Tex system. Macros can be used directly but counts boxes and other register types require a prefix accesor function

Comment: Depends on exactly what you mean, as @DavidCarlisle says. For example, a `prop` is currently a macro with certain content even when 'empty'. But your will (probably) get away with various operations even if you don't declare it first.

Comment: Note that if you _or someone else_ activates checking, then you _have_ to have declarations to avoid errors

Comment: As TeX scope is not based on macros but on explicit groups, you can never have a situation where some 'local variables' are just 'inside a macro' _unless it has a group anyway_. As I've said elsewhere, in the end it fits better into how TeX works just to declare variables globally even if they are _used_ local-to-a-group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using just `\l_siemer_foo_tl` or `\l_siemer_foo_str` instead of

```
\tl_use:N \l_siemer_foo_tl
\str_use:N \l_siemer_foo_str
```

is indeed allowed, but not really recommended. I generally try to prefix with `\tl_use:N` (or `\str_use:N` because it's cleaner programming, unless conciseness makes the “unprefixed” way preferable. Note that `\tl_use:N` requires a few expansion steps, whereas the unprefixed form only requires one and this can make a difference in an already long program.

On the other hand, `\tl_use:N` also checks whether the following variable is declared, when the `check-declarations` option is in force.

There are other `<module>_use:N` functions, namely `\dim_use:N`, `\skip_use:N`, `\muskip_use:N`, `\int_use:N`, `\box_use:N` and `\fp_use:N`; omitting these will lead to disasters.

Using *any* variable (except `tl` or `str`, as mentioned) in the wild will do nothing good; in some cases you get a sensible error, such as `A sequence was misused.` or `A floating point with value '1.2' was misused`. In other cases (think to `dim` variables) you'd get a very low level error message or unexpected output.

The only other variable type that *could* be used in the wild is `clist`, but this is just for reasons of implementation and this feature should not be relied upon. Thus `\l_siemer_foo_clist` should *not* be considered as a shorthand for `\clist_use:Nn \l_siemer_foo_clist {,}` (which I don't really see a use for anyway). Your nice program using it might no longer work because the internal implementation of `clist` variables has changed.

For other variable types there is no `<module>_use:N` function, but other arguments are needed that exploit the variable's internal structure.

And, no, `<module>_new:N` is definitely not optional, for *any* variable type.

Answer (score 7):

Any variable type that is ultimately a macro can be 'used' without an accessor. However, that might lead to surprising results: for example, take a look at the raw structure of an `fp`!

The official position on declaration of variables *will not change*: they have to be declared before use. The one exception is where they are 'auto-created' by `l3keys`: a compromise to avoid extremely repetitive code.

Comment: ...the only variable types which are officially allowed to be used without accessor function are `tl` and `str`. You have any other types in mind which would fit into this category as well?

Comment: @RobertSiemer Everything else has some internal structure, though a `clist` is really just a very restricted `tl`.

Comment: So is it okay to use clists without accessor in practice? Which should be updated: the documentation or code which uses clists without accessor?

Comment: @RobertSiemer I'm not sure what use you'd make of `\l_tmpa_clist` out in the wild; note that we have `\clist_use:Nn` and `\clist_use:Nnnn`, but no `\clist_use:N`.

Comment: ...as a shortcut for `\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {,}`

Comment: @RobertSiemer No, I don't mean this is supported, I mean that one can see that it's feasible